# Java in Chrome on OS X, enable "click to play"

Tags: google-chrome, java, plugins

How do I enable "click to play" for the Java plugin in Chrome on OS X?

If impossible, is there any way to make Chrome prompt me before running Java? I.e. is there any middle ground between disabling the plugin and enabling it always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your Chrome version?

In version 9 (which is currently in the [beta channel](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/getting-involved/dev-channel)), there is a "click to play" setting.  It's a little buggy, though, so for now it only appears after enabling the functionality in `about:flags`.